# How do I supply a Color Model to a .tiff image in Java when the image does not provide a Color Model to be used?

Tags: java, image, colors, tiff, jai

I am fairly new to Java, and so some of the classes like Color Model and JAI are not familiar to me.  I have a tiff image I am reading into a program in Java.  This is my read-in code:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
String input[] = {"LE70160412002112EDC00_sr_band5", "LE70160412002144EDC00_sr_band5"}; 
String filetype = "tif";
File file = new File(input[0] + "output.csv");
int numFiles = 0;
while (numFiles < 2){    
    if (filetype == "tif"){
        FileSeekableStream stream = new FileSeekableStream(new File(input[numFiles] + ".tif"));
        TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();
        decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
        ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
        params.add(stream);
        RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
        img = image1.getAsBufferedImage();
    }
}
```

To be clear, other things are done further down in the while loop that I excluded such that the files are not overwriting each other.  The problem I am having is not being able read in the file and get further into the loop.  I had a tiff file that only had black and white pixels (0 or 255 red value for all pixels), and the code ran correctly because the file supplied the Color Model.  The new tiff file I am trying to use is a greyscale picture (0 to 255 red value for all pixels), and every time I run the code it gives me the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ColorModel is supplied and the image ColorModel is null.
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2500)
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2546)
at Soda.DoStuff.doStuff(DoStuff.java:60)
at Soda.Driver.main(Driver.java:6)
```

My first instinct given the error message is to create a new Color Model.  There may also be a better way to use JAI to import the tiff file such that it supplies the Color Model for the greyscale image.  My end goal is to get the red value for each pixel in the image, so I do not want the data coming in to be altered from it's original form.

Any help I can get would be much appreciated.  I am open to any suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Someone commented to try and use the getDefaultColorModel class inside the PlanarImage library, so I changed the bottom line of the code to this:

```
cm = PlanarImage.getDefaultColorModel(0, 1); //
img = image1.getAsBufferedImage(null, cm);
```

This also did not completely work but provided a different error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SampleModel and ColorModel parameters must be non-null.
at com.sun.media.jai.util.JDKWorkarounds.areCompatibleDataModels(JDKWorkarounds.java:363)
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getAsBufferedImage(PlanarImage.java:2505)
at Soda.DoStuff.doStuff(DoStuff.java:64)
at Soda.Driver.main(Driver.java:6)
```

I have extensively read through https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PlanarImage.html to learn about the PlanarImage class, but I still cannot figure out how to properly format a ColorModel.  (0,1) creates a color model with 8 pixel bits and 1 component.  I also tried with (1,1) which creates a color model with 16 pixel bits and 1 component.  Both provided the same error message above.

**EDIT2:** Unfortunately, I cannot link the image itself.  However, I can tell you how I got the image from USGS.  Forewarning, getting this image requires you to make a free account, and then afterwards you have to 'order' the picture from USGS, which is simply they need to process the request and give a download link for a zip file.  It WILL take some time before you can actually access the picture.  I also suggest making the account first because it will not let you start the image checkout process until you have an account made.

Using this link, http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/, you pick a point on the map, then set the date range so that it ends on 12/31/2002 (the start date does not matter).  The go to the Data set tab where under the "Landsat Archive" bullet, you will hit the checkbox for "Landsat Surface Reflectance - L7 ETM+".  Hit OK on the dialogue, then hit "Results" at the bottom of the screen.

Once you have signed into your account and done this search, you should see many images on the left side of your screen with similar names to the filenames in my code above.  You want to hit the shopping cart next to one of the images (You only need one, my whole project required 2, but for the purposes of reading in the file, that's not necessary).  The shopping cart should turn green.  Then in the top right corner there is a link to an Item Basket.  You hit "Proceed to Checkout" and "Submit Order" on successive screens, and then you wait for an email from USGS.

Finally unzip the file, and you should have about 10 images.  As you can see in the code, I am using the image with the name "sr_band5", but I believe any of the bands are greyscale which I cannot read in.  Hope this can help.

Comment: can you link this image somewhere?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the `decodeParam` you create (and set a value for, that only makes sense for palette/indexed color images) doesn't seem to be used. The second error message/stack trace seems to indicate a JAI bug to me, but what do I know.

Comment: PS: Do you need JAI? I've created a [TIFF plugin for ImageIO](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/), that allows you to work with the more familiar ImageIO API, and handles all baseline TIFFs along with most of the popular extensions (and some less common ones).

Comment: haraldK, I tried your plugin, and while this time the code was able to get past the point of reading in the image (it had the correct width and height), it seemingly destroyed the data.  The data for every pixel was -9999, so the program could not run.  Again, being fairly new at Java, I could have implemented the jars incorrectly, but I did just use regular ImageIO with the jars in my program, and that was the result

Comment: @bew5107 I'm sorry but I can't go through all those steps to get a sample file. Maybe you could contact USGS and have them release a sample file for testing/debugging purposes? It's hard to say anything more without the sample file in question, but it's not necessarily incorrect that all pixels have the value -9999...

Comment: @haraldK Your TIFF plugin solved the problem for what I was asking, and that is how to get a TIFF file to be read into my program without needing a color model.  Using your library + standard input worked like a charm, so I would like to ask you to submit your library as an answer so I can accept it and more people can use the solution.  It led to a new problem where the getRGB function from the BufferedImage class keeps giving an Array Out of Bounds Error for my 16 bit greyscale image, but it works fine for my 8 bit black-and-white image.  Is there a mailing list for the plugin?

Comment: No mailinglist, just the normal GitHub stuff. Feel free to use the issue tracker there, if you have problems or run into bugs. If your TIFF files are 16 bit *signed* integral data, I know there's an issue with the current Java2D `ColorModel` implementation. I haven't been able to fully work around it. This may be the reason JAI don't give you a color model... You should still be able to work with the `Raster` though and access the data directly without the color model, maybe that is a better approach in this case?